# Why use sliding window input features in sequence modeling?

Tags: time-series, bioinformatics, sequence-analysis

I was reading through the DNABERT paper and found that their input features were k-mers. This is equivalent to using rolling/sliding window features in the other common family of sequential problem, time series. I have seen this be done, but is there any theory explaining why this can be beneficial?

Why would I give a transformer-like model sequences of the form {a_n,..,a_{n+k}} rather than training it on the sequence {a_1,...,a_{m}} with positional encoding?

Comment: Maybe this question is helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46327/time-series-forecasting-lookback-windows-sliding-or-growing

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question (why this can be beneficial), from a biological perspective: the reason for using short (length k) subsequences of the long sequence is that these short sequences (called DNA motifs) are often biologically relevant, especially when dealing with cis-regulatory regions, as is the point of DNABERT. This is also briefly mentioned in the material and methods section of the [DNABERT manuscript](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/37/15/2112/6128680) (2.2.1 Tokenization). At the same time, there is no delimiter in DNA sequences, and in fact multiple overlapping k-mers could exist that are relevant.

```
AGCTTAACG  | Input sequence
```

---

```
AGCT       |
 GCTT      |
  CTTA     | 4-mers
   TTAA    |
    TAAC   |
     AACG  |
```

I am not really an expert on positional encoding, but as I understand this would require some knowledge on boundaries, i.e. start and end of words. For DNA sequences, these boundaries are not known, and they are not evident from the sequence.

It could also simply be for historical reasons, k-mer based approaches for DNA sequence analysis are very popular and used in many areas of sequence research, especially for alignment and assembly of DNA. (see e.g. [Sense from sequence reads: methods for alignment and assembly](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.1376))

Comment: I don't think this really answers my question; The original input sequence already contains all the k-mers, so that information is contained there. 
And, no, positional encoding do no require one to know the end and start of words; They are even used in image transformers such as ViT to encode for position in images. Also, transformers are autoregressive, so the positional encoding can change depending upon where the word is after a few iterations.

The historical reasons argument seems to be the most convincing one at the moment.

Comment: While I cannot really add much to your original question, It seems that the drawbacks of using k-mers also occured to the authors of DNABert, and DNABert-2 uses a different tokenization. https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.15006